# Sharing code between iOS and MacOS - NSTextField and UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have an app which is largely the same between both platforms, sharing logic and object names. But the code is perforce different, and I'd like to bring it together.

I'm trying to consolidate the logic as much as possible to make maintenance easier. However on iOS I use

```
result.text = valueString
```

and in MacOS it's

```
result.stringValue = valueString
```

Is there any way I can do what I want: to share everything in my code except for the user interface definitions? I've looked at Chameleon, but it doesn't seem to stretch this far.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a protocol that both classes conform to that acts as a text accessor:

```
protocol TextAccess {
    func getText() -> String?
}

extension UITextView: TextAccess {
    func getText() -> String? {
        return text
    }
}

extension NSTextField: TextAccess {
    func getText() -> String? {
        return stringValue
    }
}
```

That way, you just call `.getText()` on any of the types to invoke their specific accessor.  You may need to wrap the code above in `#if` blocks, but this is just a rough example of one way to approach this issue.

Another approach would be to create an alias:

```
#if os(iOS)
    typealias TextField = UITextField
#endif
#if os(macOS)
    typealias TextField = NSTextField
#endif
```

Anywhere you access `TextField`, you will be accessing the platform-specific class.

Answer (score -1):

I found it. Obvious really, if you know what the specific syntax is…

```
#if os(iOS)
    result.text = valueString
#else
    result.stringValue = valueString
#endif
```

Comment: Interesting, but what would the type of `result` have to be for that to compile? I don't see how that helps you; it merely pushes the problem further back (onto the declaration of `result` itself). It doesn't ultimately "consolidate" anything.

Comment: So I noticed. The theory was good - but it means I can copy and paste the whole function, with the #if blocks in it,  between both versions of the app. I know exactly how to do it in Cobol!